# Neo4j APOC remove all triggers

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'd like to implement Cypher query and using APOC functions remove all of the existing triggers:

I'm trying the following query:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.list() yield name 
CALL apoc.trigger.remove(name) yield name, installed
```

but it fails with the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Query cannot conclude with CALL
>   (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 37 (offset: 36))
>   "CALL apoc.trigger.list() yield name CALL apoc.trigger.remove(name)
>   yield name, installed" ^

How to properly implement this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, a query cannot end with a CALL (unless the CALL is the only statement in the query). It needs either a write operation (MERGE, CREATE, SET, REMOVE, DELETE) or a return.

You can add `RETURN name, installed` at the end, if you want to return the values yielded by the call. Otherwise, if you really don't care about what is returned, `RETURN DISTINCT true` ought to do the trick.

Oh, and you may want to alias `name` in one of your YIELDs or the other, as you may get an error of a variable name conflict.